# Merge rows with same value in column A

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the columns, `movie-name` which is column `A` and then month name from column `B` to `P`.

e.g.

```
movie-name | Jan | Feb | March | April
movie1     | 0.1 |     |       |
movie2     |     | 0.4 |       |
movie2     |     |     |  0.9  | 
movie1     |     | 0.8 |       |
movie2     |     |     |       | 0.2
```

I'd like to merge column a with same movie name so the desired result is:

```
movie-name | Jan | Feb | March | April
movie1     | 0.1 | 0.8 |       |
movie2     |     | 0.4 |  0.9  | 0.2
```

How do i do this with google sheets or excel formula?

Comment: use a pivot table

Comment: You should start by sorting the rows on movie-name so all similar records are together.

Comment: In excel you can use the `group` function. 
https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/groups-and-subtotals/1/

Comment: In Google Sheets use the query function.

Answer (score 2):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

`=QUERY(filter({A:A,IFERROR(B:E*1,B:E)}, A:A<>""),
"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4), sum(Col5) group by Col1")`

- `A:A` -- column with names
- `B:E` -- columns with months
- `sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4), sum(Col5)...` add more columns for more months

[image]

Comment: the columns for dates go from `B` to `P`  do i change the `E` to `P`?

Comment: change the E to P and add more months into query

Comment: Which cell do i apply the formula to?

Comment: `=QUERY(filter({A:A,IFERROR(B:P*1,B:P)}, A:A<>""),
"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4), sum(Col5) ..., sum(ColN) group by Col1")` this is the basic logic.

Comment: I tried this and didn't work.  I highlighted cell A2 and pasted code and i get Error: circular dependency detected.

Comment: @mdnba50, I guess, the cell is placed in a range which is used in calculations. Please see my screenshot for a proper usage of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel,

```
Select the data and headings.
Choose the Data Tab and click sort.
Sort by column (movie-name) and make sure the 'My Data contains headers' checkbox is selected.
Next while the data is still highlighted and the Data tab is still open,
  Choose the SubTotal button, movie-name should be selected in the 'At each change' option,
  Select each column you want subtotaled. (Jan-Dec), Click okay.
```

You will be able to select between seeing all data, sub-totals that you are asking for and a grand-total.

[image: Subtotal summary]